# Nearest hospital in a network

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm

I have a graph representing a city. Some vertices are hospitals. The graph is connected.

I'm looking for an **algorithm that will give me the path (or even the distance) from any given node to the nearest hospital.**

One could think of computing all shortest paths, but I think they might be a smarter way.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [warshall's algorithm for shortest path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm)?

Comment: yes, but it implies computing all shortest paths, Am-I wrong?

Comment: Yes but The Floyd–Warshall algorithm typically only provides the lengths of the paths between all pairs of vertices.So after then you can compare Or use them as you want(I mean use the results/output according to your purpose)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to see [warshall's algorithm for shortest path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm).
Here is the algorithm

```
let dist be a |V| × |V| array of minimum distances initialized to ∞ (infinity)
for each vertex v
   dist[v][v] ← 0
for each edge (u,v)
   dist[u][v] ← w(u,v)  // the weight of the edge (u,v)
for k from 1 to |V|
   for i from 1 to |V|
      for j from 1 to |V|
         if dist[i][k] + dist[k][j] < dist[i][j] then
            dist[i][j] ← dist[i][k] + dist[k][j]
```

The algorithm above is executed on the graph on the left below

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3J7Sb.png 
**Reference:wikiPedia** *(link is given at the start of answer)* 
For further detail please visit the link

Comment: no worries :) but AFAIK this is the solution which we can use for this problem